# Can you crew a Vehicle that is already a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's pretend I control a [Mobile Garrison](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMobile%20Garrison%5d) and a [Veteran Motorist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVeteran%20Motorist%5d).

I crew the Garrison with my Motorists (sweet +1/+1 bonus).

I attack with the Garrison, and I untap the Motorists with the triggered ability.

At this point, can I tap the Motorists to crew the Garrison again and get another +1/+1?

Comment: If a vehicle is already a creature (perhaps because it's been crewed already, or you cast Ensoul Artifact on it or something), you can even crew it with itself, though I imagine that's a highly situational play.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can activate a Crew ability multiple times. Normally doing so doesn't do anything (other than tapping the creature used to crew the vehicle), however since the Motorist has an triggered ability that triggers on crewing a vehicle the trigger will still occur.

From the Gatherer rulings on every vehicle:

> You may activate a crew ability of a Vehicle even if it’s already an artifact creature. Doing so has no effect on the Vehicle. It doesn’t change its power and toughness.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can Crew a Vehicle while it is a creature. Adding the Creature type does not remove the Crew ability, and there is no stipulation in the Crew ability that it can only be activated if the Vehicle is not a creature.